# How to match the rows while updates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1

```
Id 

001
002
003
```

Table2

```
id 

001 
004
```

I want to display all the rows of table1 and match rows of table2 like this

Output Table

```
ID status

001 1 - Found
002 - 0
003 -0
```

1 - Found
0 - Unfound

How to acheive in SQL Query

Comment: Please read or search on `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

```
select table1.id, case when table2.id is not null 
                       then 'found' 
                  end as status
from table1
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

In the event that the second table could have duplicates, you might be better off with `exists` and `case`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
             then 'Found'
             else 'Not Found'
        end)
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) and [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)?

Something like

```
SELECT  t1.*, 
        CASE 
            WHEN t2.ID IS NOT NULL 
                THEN 'FOUND' 
            ELSE 'NOT FOUND' 
        END [Status]
FROM    Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
        Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.Id, CASE WHEN T2.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Status
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id
```

Result:

```
ID  STATUS
1   1
2   0
3   0
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a3ea/2).

If you want to display `Found` and `Not Found`:

```
SELECT T1.Id, CASE WHEN T2.id IS NULL THEN 'Not Found' ELSE 'Found' END AS Status
FROM Table1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id
```

Result:

```
ID  STATUS
1   Found
2   Not Found
3   Not Found
```

Fiddle example [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a3ea/3).

Answer (score 0):

you can use case when:

```
SELECT
    Table1.id,
    CASE WHEN
        Table2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
FROM
    Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```